# Allow CSS in particular Jenkins report

Tags: html, css, jenkins, report

I have a Jenkins job that generates an HTML report. Problem is, that by default Jenkins blocks CSS for security reasons.

Every solution I've seen online is to create a CSP rule that allows CSS from everywhere.

Is it possible to create allow CSS in a particular job?

Thanks ahead